# making matplotlib with pandas dataframe data

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pandas

I'm trying to crate a bar plot where the x-axis is column1 in my dataFrame (lets said it called "A" and it contains strings) and the y-axis is the second column (named "B" and contains integers).
I want to create a the plot and get the data from the relevant columns, and to see the x-axis labels as the strings that are in the dataFrame.

how can I do this?

Comment: Have you read http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example:

```
import pylab as plt
import pandas as pd
from random import sample

atype = list('abc'*2)
asize = sample(xrange(100), 6)

df = pd.DataFrame({'type': atype, 'size': asize})
df_grouped = df.groupby('type').sum() # sum sizes for same types
df_grouped.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```